# Align line breaks with :before selector

Tags: html, css

I've got five items that all have different content in their respective :before selectors. My goals is to have the line breaks align with the first character of the item, not the before selector.

Here's a working fiddle of what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/64hEn/

...and the code:

```
<div>
    <ul>
       <li class="first">This is something in a list</li>
       <li class="second">This is something in a list longer here that is long</li>
       <li class="third">This is something in a list this is another thing</li>
       <li class="fourth">This is something in a list something</li>
       <li class="fifth">This is something in a list this one is really really long and it could go on forever</li>
    </ul>
</div>

div{
    width: 200px;
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
}

.first:before{
    content: "First";
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #999;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}    

.second:before{
    content: "Second";
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #777;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.third:before{
    content: "Third";
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #555;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.fourth:before{
    content: "Fourth";
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.fifth:before{
    content: "Fifth";
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Here's a quick mockup of what I want: [image]

Comment: You really should not be putting what is essentially "Content" in pseudo elements. They are for styling.

Comment: @Paulie_D: I don't see a problem. This is hardly different from `list-style-type: decimal`, it's just a customized list counter.

Comment: If you are actually typing text into a `content` property...why not just type it into the `li` itself? However, each to their own

Comment: @Paulie_D The before content are icons and are added programmatically.

Comment: Clearly they aren't "icons"...they are actual text inside the `content` property....and that's my point.

Comment: Here is a fun way to do it without having to hardcode the text in the CSS (I'm not a fan of that either). http://jsfiddle.net/EUV9L/

Comment: Or, you could even just use the class name itself as the content: http://jsfiddle.net/C35yz/

Comment: @Paulie_D My point was that in the actual code, not the example, they are image icons.

Comment: @cpreid that works for the example, thanks. The actual code though has a sprite sheet that grabs the image icon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing something like this. I cleaned up your repetitive CSS a bit. I needed to add a span element to get the desired look.

http://jsfiddle.net/XbxhZ/

```
<li class="first"><span>This is something in a list</span></li>

.magic ul li span {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:100px;
}

.magic ul li:before {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #555;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    width:50px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Rather than hardcoding 'First, second, third' in the css. You can use the dynamic content selector in CSS, in order to use the classname itself as the label.

```
.magic ul li:before {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #555;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    width:50px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    content: attr(class);
}
```

Comment: I propose that the filter checks that a user has provided code, or has provided a link to a fiddle or codepen (makes sense within a web topic: html, js, css, etc). Having to copy and paste the revised code from JSFiddle in order to pass a filter seems silly.

Comment: Well, I don't know about the other sites, but JSFiddle is incredibly notorious for its downtimes - and the most popular one to boot. I find myself randomly unable to access it multiple times a day. It does help to have the code listed within SO.

Comment: All good points. Also it helps with SEO for the page, i imagine :)

Comment: I guess my only issue with this answer is getting the span tags into the generated list. I was looking for an answer with the provided HTML, but I suppose this is somewhat correct.